# Windows API - scan for BLE devices before using BluetoothGATTGetServices

Tags: windows, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to get BLE ported to Windows.

I found how to use BluetoothGATTGetServices to get the device services, but I am not sure is there a way to scan for BLE devices and obtain the hDevice handle? I found ways to obtain the handle using paired devices, but in my case the device is not paird.

Comment: It depends on Windows version. on Win 10 you have to use BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher Class. It's from WinRT API.

Comment: Hello,
Yes I have seen this, but this means use WinRT API. Indeed I have the app working using WinRT but it is dead slow, so I was hoping the non WinRT option will be fast enough. What I am trying to achieve:
1) I have custom BLE dongle that implements half of the logic (BRSP stack) and it is fast enough
2) I decided to use built in BT instead of paying for custom dongle (app is old Win32) but WinRT is too slow (missing frames), so my hope was that the native api will ne fast enough!

Thanks allot for your help!

Comment: WinRT is fast enought as well. Take a look on Bluetooth Framework (https://www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm). WinRT uses the same Windows Bluetooth stack so it works identical (with just a different API).

Comment: By the way, I forgot to say that you can use WinRT to find and pair your device and then you can switch to legacy GATT API if you would like (Bluetooth Framework also allows to do that).

Comment: Hello,
So you suggest that I scan an connect using WinRT and then SetupDiGetClassDevs will be able to find this device?

Comment: No. You can scan and pair with WinRT API and then use SetupDiGetClassDevs

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the protocols you are trying to implement, but standart service for advertising and scanning is GAP, which is interconnected with GATT. Make sure your device has both of the services and than implement the method for scanning for bluetooth devices. As I understand you are trying to make some sort of application for the computer which would scan for the devices. I don't know much about BLE development for windows but i guess you can implement some simple python script like

```
import bluetooth
devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(lookup_names = true)
for addr, name in devices:
   print("adress :", addr)
   print("name :", name)
```